# How to create a sudo user if there is no wheel group available in rhel?

Tags: linux, sudo, redhat-enterprise-linux, root

I mean,

if there's a user with username:**name**

how to make him a sudo user without adding him to wheel group(intention is if wheel group is deleted)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add that user directly to /etc/sudoers or add a group to sudoers that the user is also in. Most distros use the commend visudo to edit this file.

Comment: ## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
    root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL

Comment: We can add a new user below this line.

Answer (score 2):

Run:
visudo

Add that user, preferably at the bottom of the file under your own comment like:

```
#Admins
username    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

or I like create an admin group like this:

```
User_Alias ROOTUSERS = jpratt

ROOTUSERS ALL=(ALL) ALL
```